# storing value of ImplicitSourceTerm

Tags: fipy

I am working with fipy and I wish to simulate a flow with a free flux BC on some selected faces.
Following [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836864/fixed-flux-boundary-conditions-in-fipy) [examples](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html), I tried 2 different technics:

```
from fipy import *
from fipy.meshes.nonUniformGrid1D import NonUniformGrid1D as Grid1D
from fipy.tools import numerix as np

dx = [1.,  1. , 0.78584047] 
coeff = 2.
dt = min(0.1, 0.9 * min(dx) ** 2 / (2 * coeff))
steps = 10

mesh = Grid1D(nx = len(dx), dx = dx)

#phi values 
phi = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value=[10., 0., 0.], hasOld = True)
phi.constrain(0., mesh.facesRight) #dirichlet BC
phi2 = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value=[10., 0., 0.], hasOld = True)
phi2.constrain(0., mesh.facesRight) #dirichlet BC

#outflow value
phi2Out = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value=[0., 0., 0.], hasOld = True)

intCoef = FaceVariable(mesh, value=coeff)
extCoef = FaceVariable(mesh, value=coeff)
intCoef.constrain(0., where = mesh.facesRight)
extCoef.constrain(0., where = ~mesh.facesRight)

eq1= TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff= intCoef * phi.faceValue) \
  + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff= (extCoef * phi.faceGrad).divergence)
  
eq2 =TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff= intCoef * phi2.faceValue) \
  + phi2 * (extCoef * phi2.faceGrad).divergence
  
eq3 =TransientTerm() == - phi2 * (extCoef * phi2.faceGrad).divergence

phi.updateOld()
phi2.updateOld()
phi2Out.updateOld()
    
for _ in range(steps):
    res =  1e+10
    loop = 0
    while res > 1e-4 and loop < 1000:
        res =  eq1.sweep(var= phi,dt= dt)
        res2 =  eq2.sweep(var=phi2 ,dt= dt)
        res3 =  eq3.sweep(var=phi2Out ,dt= dt)
        res = max(res, res2, res3)
        loop += 1
    if res > 1e-4:
        print('no convergence! res: ', res)
        break
        
    phi.updateOld()
    phi2.updateOld()
    phi2Out.updateOld()
    
    print('\nphi: ', phi * mesh.cellVolumes, sum(phi* mesh.cellVolumes))
    print('phi2: ', phi2* mesh.cellVolumes,sum(phi2* mesh.cellVolumes))
    print('phi2_outFlow: ', phi2Out* mesh.cellVolumes, sum(phi2Out* mesh.cellVolumes))
    print('phi2_total: ', sum(phi2* mesh.cellVolumes + phi2Out* mesh.cellVolumes))
```

Output after 10 steps:

phi:  [2.21786728 1.82700906 0.63381385] 4.678690190704105

phi2:  [2.21786872 1.82701185 0.6338187 ] 4.678699267591382

phi2_outFlow:  [0.         0.         5.32132192] 5.321321918864122

phi2_total:  10.000021186455504

Ideally, I would like to extract the value of the outflow to check the mass balance and know the exact value of each term for each cell (other sink/source terms will be added later, as well as other free-flow boundaries).

My questions are:

1. why are the values of phi and phi2 slightly different?
2. how could I extract the outflow term for each cell (when a more complex grid will be used) while keeping 'ImplicitSourceTerm', which is more efficient?

Thank you for your help!

PS: I have been working with python3 so far, so, although I am interested in solutions involving other solvers, I am especially looking for something that can be implemented with scipy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why are the values of phi and phi2 slightly different?

`phi` and `phi2` are different because `eq2` doesn't converge as rapidly as `eq1`. This is because `eq1` is more implicit than `eq2`. If you change the tolerance for the residual, e.g., `res > 1e-10`, you'll see the two solutions are in much closer agreement.

> 2. how could I extract the outflow term for each cell (when a more complex grid will be used) while keeping 'ImplicitSourceTerm', which is more efficient?

You can still evaluate the flux `phi2 * extCoef * phi2.faceGrad`, even when you use the `ImplicitSourceTerm`.

In general, it's not easy to extract what each `Term` is doing physically (see issue [#461](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/461)). You can use the [`FIPY_DISPLAY_MATRIX`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#envvar-FIPY_DISPLAY_MATRIX) environment variable to see how each `Term` contributes to the solution matrix, but this may or may not give you much physical intuition for what's going on.